# How to fix authentication interuption in community Rundeck v4.12.0?

Tags: apt-get, rundeck

I upgraded my Rundeck instance from v3.1.6 to v4.12.0 recently via `apt-get`. I use Firefox and found no issues along the way nor after getting getting to v4.12.0. Other users who access our Rundeck instance via Chrome or Safari later found that when they authenticated with their username and password that the page hung. If a user opens a new tab in the same browser they attempted to login from and goes to the Rundeck url it brings them to the dashboard fully logged in. This does not happen in Firefox.

**Browser versions where respective behavior is seen:**
Firefox 112.0 (20230406114409)
Chrome 96.0.4664.93
Chrome 112.0.5615.137
Safari 16.4 (18615.1.26.11.23)

When I watch the network traffic in Chrome dev tools I see the authentication process hanging on `j_security_check`. There is a corresponding error noted:

| Resource | Status | Directive |
| --- | --- | --- |
| https://<RUNDECK_URL>/j_security_check | blocked | form-action |

Looking at rundeck.audit.events.log I can see that users login attempts from all browsers are showing `ActionType='login_success'`. When sessions are initiated from either Chrome or Safari the login process hangs. When sessions are initiated from Firefox the login process completes.

Comment: Hi! Pretty sure that you're facing this: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/4417 Ensure to set the `grails.ServerURL` parameter (on the `rundeck-config.properties` file) pointing to the right LB/proxy rundeck exit URL and set the `-Drundeck.jetty.connector.forwarded=true` (`rundeck-config.properties` file too). Take a look at this: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/4417#issuecomment-457548602

Comment: Thanks @MegaDrive68k, this does look like it could be my answer or at least point me to it.  I have priorities that have came up preventing me from working on it right now.  I'll follow up with results when I am able to.